# git merge fails refusing to lose untracked file

Tags: git

I am trying to merge a repository on the master. 
I am getting the following error.

```
error: refusing to lose untracked file at 'config/database.yml'
```

git status gives me

```
deleted by us:   config/database.yml
```

How can I resolve that ?

Comment: Did you recently have `database.yml` added to your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: yes I have recently added that file on my gitignore.

Comment: Was it the branch that you were trying to merge that had the ignored file, or is it `master` that's ignoring it?

Comment: Both .gitignore files have the /config/database.yml file.

Answer (score 10):

From what you're describing, the `database.yml` file just shouldn't be in your repository anymore.

Perform `git rm --cached config/database.yml` to remove it from Git, then attempt your merge once more.